# How to implement 3D space diving using 2D graphic

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, xna, 2d

I'm trying to get something like this 
http://www.fotosearch.com/CSV008/k6834584/

But I have a trouble with moving stars at 2D screen.

I'm looking for algoritm, that simulate 3D space diving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is extremely vague, I doubt you will be able to get a satisfying answer this way.
If you have already tried implementing this, you should show your code and the specific parts you are having trouble with.
I would think the most important basic points to keep in mind would be that

1. the stars get bigger as they approach the screen
2. stars that are not exactly in the center of the screen would move away to the sides as they got closer
3. stars need to be removed once they pass a certain threshold of proximity to the "camera"

Its perfectly feasible to implement something as simple as this using GDI+, however, more complex scenarios should probably be solved using some form of 3D graphics library (like Direct3D) to take care of perspective and projection.